# C++ Windows Owner Drawn Main Menu -- itemID

Tags: c++, windows, menu, ownerdrawn

I am attempting to create an owner-drawn main menu, in Windows.  I understand setting:

`menuiteminfo.ftype = MFT_OWNERDRAW`

I also know about handling the WM_MEASUREITEM and WM_DRAWITEM messages.

However, how do I know *which* main menu item is sending the message? (so that I can fill-in the appropriate box size and text)  "itemID" seems to be the only unique identifier.  But, how can I associate this pointer/handle to the item in question?  I can use "lParam" to determine it is a menu item.  But, I can't determine which menu item.  "GetMenuItemID" is useless, as it returns "-1" for all main-menu items.

Or, am I going about this all-wrong?  I have been searching for answers, for weeks.  Really, all I want to do is change the text color of the main menu, from black, to white or light gray, so I can use a dark background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `itemID` field of the `MEASUREITEMSTRUCT` and `DRAWITEMSTRUCT` structs tells you exactly which menu item is being measured/drawn.  This is the ID that *you* specify when you create/modify a menu item.  That ID is specified via either:

- the `uIDNewItem` parameter of `AppendMenu()`, `InsertMenu()`, or `ModifyMenu()`.
- the `item` parameter of `InsertMenuItem()` or `SetMenuItemInfo()`
- the `wID` field of the `MENUITEMINFO` struct that you pass to `InsertMenuItem()` or `SetMenuItemInfo()`.

Use whatever IDs you want, as long as they are unique for your menus.

You can also use the `itemData` field of `MEASUREITEMSTRUCT` and `DRAWITEMSTRUCT` to receive any custom data you want for owner-drawn menu items, if you so desire (like, for example, a pointer to a buffer that contains a menu item's text string).  This custom value can be anything you want that is meaningful for you.  You set this value in the `dwItemData` field of the `MENUITEMINFO` struct that you pass to `InsertMenuItem()` or `SetMenuItemInfo()`.

This is all covered in the documentation:

[Using Menus: Creating Owner Drawn Menu Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-menus#creating-owner-drawn-menu-items)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Remy.  Through the items that you mentioned, and researching the documentation for each, I was able to find a buried secret.  For a Main Menu item, the "itemID" in both the MEASUREITEMSTRUCT and DRAWITEMSTRUCT is the handle to the drop-down menu of that item.  From that, I added this line of code to WM_CREATE, to associate the itemID with the numerical (zero-based) position:

`mItemID[i] = int(GetSubMenu(hMenu, i));`

'i' is the numerical position, from left to right.  I can then use a comparison statement like this, in WM_MEASUREITEM and WM_DRAWITEM:

`lpmis=(LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT)lParam;      if(lpmis->itemID==mItemID[i])`